# Formatted HTML Report of win32_Service involving multiple specific services

Tags: powershell

Im stuck in a Filtering / Formating issue.

Goal:
Provide a customer readable output exported to HTML for easy viewing.

Required:
Filtering multiple services along with their data to be displayed in the report.

Issue:
Gathering/Parsing the data in its needed form using win32_service to query specific services.

```
#CODE
  # First lets create a text file, where we will later save the Service Health  info
  $ServiceHealthFileName = "ServiceHealth.htm"
  $serverlist = "mylistofservers.txt"
  $warning = "Stopped"
  New-Item -ItemType file $ServiceHealthFileName -Force

# Function to write the HTML Header to the file
Function writeHtmlHeader
{
param($fileName)
$date = ( get-date ).ToString('yyyy/MM/dd')
Add-Content $fileName "<html>"
Add-Content $fileName "<head>"
Add-Content $fileName "<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'>"
Add-Content $fileName '<title> Server Health</title>'
add-content $fileName '<STYLE TYPE="text/css">'
add-content $fileName  "<!--"
add-content $fileName  "td {"
add-content $fileName  "font-family: Tahoma;"
add-content $fileName  "font-size: 11px;"
add-content $fileName  "border-top: 1px solid #999999;"
add-content $fileName  "border-right: 1px solid #999999;"
add-content $fileName  "border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;"
add-content $fileName  "border-left: 1px solid #999999;"
add-content $fileName  "padding-top: 0px;"
add-content $fileName  "padding-right: 0px;"
add-content $fileName  "padding-bottom: 0px;"
add-content $fileName  "padding-left: 0px;"
add-content $fileName  "}"
add-content $fileName  "body {"
add-content $fileName  "margin-left: 5px;"
add-content $fileName  "margin-top: 5px;"
add-content $fileName  "margin-right: 0px;"
add-content $fileName  "margin-bottom: 10px;"
add-content $fileName  ""
add-content $fileName  "table {"
add-content $fileName  "border: thin solid #000000;"
add-content $fileName  "}"
add-content $fileName  "-->"
add-content $fileName  "</style>"
Add-Content $fileName "</head>"
Add-Content $fileName "<body>"

add-content $fileName  "<table width='100%'>"
add-content $fileName  "<tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>"
add-content $fileName  "<td colspan='7' height='25' align='center'>"
add-content $fileName  "<font face='tahoma' color='#003399' size='4'><strong> Server Health - $date</strong></font>"
add-content $fileName  "</td>"
add-content $fileName  "</tr>"
add-content $fileName  "</table>"

}

# Function to write the HTML Header to the file
Function writeTableHeader
{
param($fileName)

Add-Content $fileName "<tr bgcolor=#CCCCCC>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='10%' align='center'>Name</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='50%' align='center'>ProcessId</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='10%' align='center'>State</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='10%' align='center'>StartMode</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='10%' align='center'>ExitCode</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='10%' align='center'>Status</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "</tr>"
}

Function writeHtmlFooter
{
param($fileName)

Add-Content $fileName "</body>"
Add-Content $fileName "</html>"
}

Function writeServiceInfo
{
param($fileName,$SvcName,$SvcPID,$SvcSM,$SvcExCd,$ServiceState,$SvcStatus)
$SvcName= $Item.Name
$SvcPID= $Item.ProcessId
$SvcSM= $Item.StartMode
$SvcExCd= $Item.ExitCode
$ServiceState= $Item.State
$SvcStatus= $Item.Status
 if ($ServiceState -eq $warning)
 {
 Add-Content $fileName "<tr>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$SvcName</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$SvcPID</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td bgcolor='#FBB917' align=center>$ServiceState</td>"
 # #FBB917
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$SvcSM</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$SvcExCd</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$SvcStatus</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "</tr>"
 }
 else
 {
 Add-Content $fileName "<tr>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$SvcName</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$SvcPID</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$ServiceState</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$SvcSM</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$SvcExCd</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$SvcStatus</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "</tr>"
 }
}

#Function sendEmail 
#{ param($from,$to,$subject,$smtphost,$htmlFileName) 
#$body = Get-Content $htmlFileName 
#$smtp= New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient $smtphost 
#$msg = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $from, $to, $subject, $body 
#$msg.isBodyhtml = $true 
#$smtp.send($msg) 



writeHtmlHeader $ServiceHealthFileName
foreach ($server in Get-Content $serverlist)
{
 Add-Content $ServiceHealthFileName "<table width='100%'><tbody>"
 Add-Content $ServiceHealthFileName "<tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>"
 Add-Content $ServiceHealthFileName "<td width='100%' align='center' colSpan=6><font face='tahoma' color='#003399' size='2'><strong> $server </strong></font></td>"
 Add-Content $ServiceHealthFileName "</tr>"

 writeTableHeader $ServiceHealthFileName

 $store = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $name -Filter "Name LIKE 'ss0'" ;Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $name -Filter "Name LIKE 'ss1'";Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $name -Filter "Name LIKE 'ss2'";Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $name -Filter "Name LIKE 'ss3'";Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $name -Filter "Name LIKE 'ss4'";Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $name -Filter "Name LIKE 'ss5'";Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $name -Filter "Name LIKE 'ss6'";Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $name -Filter "Name LIKE 'ss7'" 
#The below would not let me create objects in the store it had an error.
 #store = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $name -Filter "Name LIKE 'ss0'"
 #$store = $store + Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $name -Filter "Name LIKE 'ss1'" 
 #$store = $store + Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $name -Filter "Name LIKE 'ss2'" 
 #$store = $store + Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $name -Filter "Name LIKE 'ss3'" 
 #$store = $store + Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $name -Filter "Name LIKE 'ss4'" 
 #$store = $store + Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $name -Filter "Name LIKE 'ss5'" 
 #$store = $store + Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $name -Filter "Name LIKE 'ss6'" 
 #$store = $store + Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $name -Filter "Name LIKE 'ss7'"
 foreach ($item in $store)
 {
 Write-Host  $item.Name $item.Name $item.FreeSpace $item.Size
 writeServiceInfo $ServiceHealthFileName $item.Name $item.ProcessId $item.State $item.StartMode $Item.ExitCode $Item.Status

 }
}
writeHtmlFooter $ServiceHealthFileName
$date = ( get-date ).ToString('yyyy/MM/dd')
```

My output file is populating correctly but only for the first service.
I get the server name and all the statuses exactly how I want them.
Im not sure what I am missing.

Out of respect this is a chopped version of a diskspace script that I got as an example from a coworker. Kudos to the original writer of whom I do not know.

Comment: Server Health - 2016/12/20
site1
Name ProcessId          State     StartMode ExitCode Status
 ss0           23164        Running            Auto        0            OK
site 2
Name ProcessId    State StartMode ExitCode Status
ss0            23164  Running       Auto               0   OK
site3
Name ProcessId    State StartMode ExitCode Status
 ss0            23164  Running      Auto              0           OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The finished code. I added an uptime to the report. Thanks to everyone for the help @MikeGaruccio . Since this was modified from another authors DiskSpace script, Thank you if you see this. In the spirit of the community here is the code for a nice Report of services with a little logic for stopped services.

```
# First lets create a text file, where we will later save the Service Health info
$ServiceHealthFileName = "ServiceHealth.htm"
$serverlist = "yourserverlist.txt"
$warning = "Stopped"
New-Item -ItemType file $ServiceHealthFileName -Force

# Function to write the HTML Header to the file
Function writeHtmlHeader
{
param($fileName)
$date = ( get-date ).ToString('yyyy/MM/dd')
Add-Content $fileName "<html>"
Add-Content $fileName "<head>"
Add-Content $fileName "<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;    charset=iso-8859-1'>"
Add-Content $fileName '<title> Server Health</title>'
add-content $fileName '<STYLE TYPE="text/css">'
add-content $fileName  "<!--"
add-content $fileName  "td {"
add-content $fileName  "font-family: Tahoma;"
add-content $fileName  "font-size: 11px;"
add-content $fileName  "border-top: 1px solid #999999;"
add-content $fileName  "border-right: 1px solid #999999;"
add-content $fileName  "border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;"
add-content $fileName  "border-left: 1px solid #999999;"
add-content $fileName  "padding-top: 0px;"
add-content $fileName  "padding-right: 0px;"
add-content $fileName  "padding-bottom: 0px;"
add-content $fileName  "padding-left: 0px;"
add-content $fileName  "}"
add-content $fileName  "body {"
add-content $fileName  "margin-left: 5px;"
add-content $fileName  "margin-top: 5px;"
add-content $fileName  "margin-right: 0px;"
add-content $fileName  "margin-bottom: 10px;"
add-content $fileName  ""
add-content $fileName  "table {"
add-content $fileName  "border: thin solid #000000;"
add-content $fileName  "}"
add-content $fileName  "-->"
add-content $fileName  "</style>"
Add-Content $fileName "</head>"
Add-Content $fileName "<body>"
add-content $fileName  "<table width='100%'>"
add-content $fileName  "<tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>"
add-content $fileName  "<td colspan='7' height='25' align='center'>"
add-content $fileName  "<font face='tahoma' color='#003399' size='4'><strong> Server Health - $date</strong></font>"
add-content $fileName  "</td>"
add-content $fileName  "</tr>"
add-content $fileName  "</table>"

}

# Function to write the HTML Header to the file
Function writeTableHeader
{
param($fileName)

Add-Content $fileName "<tr bgcolor=#CCCCCC>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='10%' align='center'>Name</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='50%' align='center'>ProcessId</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='10%' align='center'>State</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='10%' align='center'>StartMode</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='10%' align='center'>ExitCode</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='10%' align='center'>Status</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "</tr>"
}

Function writeHtmlFooter
{
param($fileName)

Add-Content $fileName "</body>"
Add-Content $fileName "</html>"
}

Function writeServiceInfo
{
param($fileName,$SvcName,$SvcPID,$SvcSM,$SvcExCd,$ServiceState,$SvcStatus)
$SvcName= $Item.Name
$SvcPID= $Item.ProcessId
$SvcSM= $Item.StartMode
$SvcExCd= $Item.ExitCode
$ServiceState= $Item.State
$SvcStatus= $Item.Status
#You can add multiple elseif statements if you wish to display certain events. I have server state of STOPPED in Red.
if ($ServiceState -eq $warning)
{
Add-Content $fileName "<tr>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td>$SvcName</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td>$SvcPID</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td bgcolor='#FF4C4C'  align=center>$ServiceState</td>"
#FF4C4C RED #FBB917 ORANGE
Add-Content $fileName "<td>$SvcSM</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td>$SvcExCd</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td>$SvcStatus</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "</tr>"
}
else
{
Add-Content $fileName "<tr>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td>$SvcName</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td>$SvcPID</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td>$ServiceState</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td>$SvcSM</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td>$SvcExCd</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td>$SvcStatus</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "</tr>"
}
}

#The function for the sendemail at the end.

#Function sendEmail 
#{ param($from,$to,$subject,$smtphost,$htmlFileName) 
#$body = Get-Content $htmlFileName 
#$smtp= New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient $smtphost 
#$msg = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $from, $to, $subject, $body 
#$msg.isBodyhtml = $true
#$smtp.send($msg) 



writeHtmlHeader $ServiceHealthFileName
foreach ($server in Get-Content $serverlist)
{
 #This adds the Uptime for the server you will need $Display in your add-content.
 $hostname = get-wmiobject win32_computersystem -computername $server | fl model
 $os = Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $server
 $uptime = (Get-Date) - ($os.ConvertToDateTime($os.lastbootuptime))
 $Display = "Uptime: " + $Uptime.Days + " days, " + $Uptime.Hours + " hours, " + $Uptime.Minutes + " minutes"

 #This builds the header for each server and include the name and uptime.
 Add-Content $ServiceHealthFileName "<table width='100%'><tbody>"
 Add-Content $ServiceHealthFileName "<tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>"
 Add-Content $ServiceHealthFileName "<td width='100%' align='center' colSpan=6><font face='tahoma' color='#003399' size='2'><strong> $server $Display </strong></font></td>"
 Add-Content $ServiceHealthFileName "</tr>"

 #This writes the header and builds the body of each server health
 writeTableHeader $ServiceHealthFileName
 $store = @()
 $store += Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $server -Filter "Name LIKE 'yourservice'"
 $store += Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $server -Filter "Name LIKE 'yourservice'"
 $store += Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $server -Filter "Name LIKE 'yourservice'"
 $store += Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $server -Filter "Name LIKE 'yourservice'"
 $store += Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $server -Filter "Name LIKE 'yourservice'"
 $store += Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $server -Filter "Name LIKE 'yourservice'"
 $store += Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $server -Filter "Name LIKE 'yourservice'"
 $store += Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $server -Filter "Name LIKE 'yourservice'"

 #This write the body of each header in the order you defined
 foreach ($item in $store)
 {
 #If you dont want on screen read out as the script progresses; comment out the write-host line.
 #Write-Host  $server $item.Name $item.ProcessId $item.State
 writeServiceInfo $ServiceHealthFileName $item.Name $item.ProcessId    $item.State $item.StartMode $Item.ExitCode $Item.Status
 }
 }
#This writes the footer
writeHtmlFooter $ServiceHealthFileName
$date = ( get-date ).ToString('yyyy/MM/dd')
#Use the below line to setup an email of the report,

#sendEmail emailaddress emailaddress "Server Status Report - $Date" EmailServer $ServiceHealthFileName
```

Answer (score 2):

Your only storing one of your service objects into the `$store` variable, the rest are just being emitted to the pipeline.  make `$store` an array and then add elements to it.

```
$store = @()
$store += Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $name -Filter "Name LIKE 'ss0'"
$store += Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $name -Filter "Name LIKE 'ss1'"
```

Also please don't string together multiple lines into one using `;` unless you have a really good reason for doing so(which is virtually never in PowerShell), it just makes your code really unclear and doesn't do anything a carriage return doesn't.

Comment: I did that as a final troubleshooting step :) Let me go back and change it back to an array and see what happens. Im pretty positive I have already tried it. Ill report back. Thanks!

Comment: I went back and rebuilt the array. It did work as I found a few spare characters in my original code. Thank you for leading me back to that. One thing is all my PIDs are the same for each service at every site. Same with my other '$Item' properties.

Comment: oh just saw that loop problem, you need to use `$server` rather than `$name` not sure where `$name` is being defined but it's nowhere in the code that's posted and I'm guessing it is a static variable somewhere else in your code

Comment: haha. Nice catch. I would have starred at that. its another variable I use for `$server` when something requires FQDN.

Answer (score 0):

### WMI Output All Services

If you don't mind using the built-in WMI output format, then this one-liner will accomplish exporting a listing of all services in table-format to HTML. If you needed this to run on multiple remote machines that can be accomplished with the `/node:` switch.

```
wmic /OUTPUT:%userprofile%\Desktop\%computername%_svc.html SERVICE list full /format:htable
```